# functions find doubled letter in tuple, how can the output change to alphabetical order by the doubled letters

Tags: python, for-loop, tuples, double

functions find doubled letter in tuple, how can the output change to alphabetical order by the doubled letters

```
countries = ('France','Marshall Islands','Greece','Morocco','Seychelles')
list3 = []
list4 = []
for i in countries:
    list3.append("".join(i))
for word in list3:
    for index, character in enumerate(word[:-1]):
        if word[index + 1] == character:
            list4.append(word)
            final_country_tuple = tuple(dict.fromkeys(list4))
            final_country_list = list(dict.fromkeys(list4))


print((final_country_tuple))

expected output = ('Morocco','Greece','Marshall islands','Seychelles')
```

Answer (score 0):

I'll be the first to admit this is a bit tricky. ;^)

- `get_doubled_char` returns the first letter of the first letter pair it encounters in a string or None if no letter pairs.
- `doubled_countries` is a list of tuples where the first field in the tuple is the country name of a letter pair country and the second element is the result from `get_doubled_char` - also the field used to sort the list.
- `final_country_tuple` builds a tuple from `doubled_countries` using only the country field.

```
def get_doubled_char(string):
    current_char_list, next_char_list = tee(list(string), 2)
    next(next_char_list)

    for current_char, next_char in zip(current_char_list, next_char_list):
        if current_char == next_char:
            return current_char
        
    return None

countries = ('France','Marshall Islands','Greece','Morocco','Seychelles')

doubled_countries = []
for country in countries:
    doubled_char = get_doubled_char(country)
    if doubled_char:
        doubled_countries.append((country, doubled_char))
doubled_countries.sort(key=lambda t: t[1])

final_country_tuple = tuple(
    country
    for country, _ in doubled_countries
)
print(final_country_tuple)
```

```
('Morocco', 'Greece', 'Marshall Islands', 'Seychelles')
```